NextAuth token to Axios interceptor
I am using NextAuth with NextJS APP Route. And Axios for make API calls. But in my case I need to pass token in AXIOS interceptor. That's why previously I was used manually handle token in cookies without nextauth. But Now I want to achieve this with nextauth. Any help to do this?
I tried to use useSession but it's have some undefined state.
